# Can you split maximally entangled qudits into maximally entangled lower-dimensional qudits?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Suppose you have qudits A and B. They are each of some large dimensionality d and are maximally entangled with each other. Is it possible, by some protocol, to split these two qudits into C, D, E, & F each with some lower dimensionality than d and still maximally entangled with each other?

Comment: I think you'd need to clarify what kind of entanglement you want on the final qudits. For multipartite states there are equivalent types of "maximally entangled" states. Or in other words, there isn't a unique notion of "maximal entanglement".

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, under certain conditions:

1. If the goal is to preserve the original state, so that it may be recovered from the split system, then the total dimensionality of the split system must be greater than or equal to that of the original qudit. However if the split system is of greater dimensionality, it will not be maximally entangled with the other half.
2. If the goal is that the final system is maximally entangled with the other half, then the total dimensionality of the split system must be less than or equal to that of the original. If the split system is smaller than the original, then the original state cannot be recovered.

If you want 1 and 2, then the initial and final dimensions must be equal. This is only possible if the original qudit dimension is a composite (*i.e.* not prime) integer.

To see an example, consider the maximally entangled state of two 4-level qudits

$|0_A0_B\rangle + |1_A1_B\rangle + |2_A2_B\rangle + |3_A3_B\rangle$

where $A$ and $B$ index the two parties Alice and Bob sharing the entangled state, and dropping normalization for convenience. Now bring in four new qubits initialized in $|0\rangle$, two in Alice's possession and two in Bob's. Alice applies a unitary with the following action:

$$|000\rangle \rightarrow |000\rangle \\
|100\rangle \rightarrow |001\rangle \\
|200\rangle \rightarrow |010\rangle \\
|300\rangle \rightarrow |011\rangle \\$$

where the first index is that of the 4-level system and the second two are the states of the two qubits. This is just mapping the state of the 4-level system to its binary representation. The process is reversible and maps orthogonal states to orthogonal states, so we can find a unitary that implements it. If Bob does the same thing, then the final state of the shared system is

$|0_A\rangle \otimes (|00_A 00_B\rangle + |01_A 01_B\rangle + |10_A 10_B\rangle + |11_A 11_B\rangle) \otimes|0_B\rangle$

This state is equivalent to the original state. We can verify that it is maximally entangled by noting that if we ignore (trace out) Bob's part of the system, Alice's qubits are in a uniform mixture of 00, 01, 10 and 11.

This procedure lets us take a pair of maximally entangled d-dits and map it to a composite system of dimension $d_1\times d_2 ...\times d_n = d$, where $d_i$ is the dimension of the $i$th qudit of the composite. Above we had $d_1=d_2=2$.

However if $d$ is prime, then there are no integers $d_i$ that multiply to $d$. We could use a set of $d_i$s that multiply to something larger than $d$, but then the resulting state is not maximally entangled (case 1). For example if we try to use the above example to encode two 3-level systems into two qubits, the final state is

$|0_A\rangle \otimes (|00_A 00_B\rangle + |01_A 01_B\rangle + |10_A 10_B\rangle) \otimes|0_B\rangle$

Now Alice's qubits are never in the 11 state, and thus they are not maximally entangled with Bob's.

But what if we only want that the final state is maximally entangled, even if it's smaller (case 2)? We can deterministically project a $d$-dimensional maximally entangled qudit state to a $d'$-dimensional maximally entangled qudit of dimension $d'<d$. To do so, consider the qudit projection operators

$$\Pi_i = \sum_{j \neq i} |j\rangle \langle j|$$

Although these projectors are not orthonormal, $\sum_i \Pi_i \propto I$, which implies that they actually do form a valid measurement basis (look up the POVM formalism for more details). Measuring either qudit in this basis will project the total to a maximally entangled qudit state of dimension $d-1$. We can repeat this procedure to get a $d'<d$-dimensional maximally entangled state, and then use the the above procedure. It's also easy to write down a measurement basis that immediately projects to $d'$ dimensions.

Comment: *"As long as the total dimensionality of the new system is at least as big as that of the original system."* -- Quite the contrary is true: This conversion can be done deterministically as long as the total dimensionality **decreases**. (As you point out yourself, if the dimension increases, the state is not maximally entangled.)

Comment: Well this is what I meant by 'there it a catch,' but the answer at the top is poorly worded. Will fix later.

Comment: I agree that you can also compress to a smaller dimensional system if you're willing to wind up with less entanglement in the end. But how would you do this deterministically?  I only see ways to do this probabilistically, with measurement.

Comment: That's a standard protocol in single-copy entanglement conversion. If d is the target dimension, basically you want to write down projectors onto d-dimensional subspaces such that these projectors add up to a multiple of the identity (worst case, pick all projections onto subspaces spanned by any d computational basis states). Then (after normalizing) this defines a POVM, which will have the desired effect. (Note that while it is deterministic, it is obviously not reversible.)

Comment: OK answer should be correct now. I guess case 1 may be less relevant to the question as worded, but I left it in case this is what OP had in mind.