# Is it possible to conduct quantum teleportation with a larger than necessary e-dit and preserve entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation

Suppose you have an e-bit between qubits A and B. You want to transfer the state of qubit Q to B. You can utilize this e-bit to perform a quantum teleportation to achieve this.

Now instead suppose that Q remains a qubit, but A and B are qudits of some higher dimensionality. Similarly, instead of an e-bit, they now instead are an e-dit of that higher dimensionality. As performing a teleportation of Q to B only requires an e-bit, is it possible to still perform this teleportation using the e-dit (only doing a weak measurement of A instead of a full measurement as is done to Q) and in doing so preserve some entanglement between A and B post-teleportation? That is, Q is fully written to B, but there is "extra space" on B that remains entangled with A?

Comment: if I understand correctly, you're asking whether you can teleport a qubit using as resource a pair of entangled (higher-dimensional) qudits, preserving the "fraction of initial entanglement" not necessary for the teleportation?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean to ask.

Comment: Basically -- using the correct answer to your other question -- you should split up the ME state into two ME states, where one is just big enough to be used for teleportation. (In fact, if the numbers do not divide, there might even be ways to sometimes get more entanglement.)

Comment: Essentially what I was asking about here as a first step? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/804175/can-you-split-maximally-entangled-qudits-of-some-large-dimensionality-into-a-lar